# how can I be sure dlopen work properly

Tags: c++, c, linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to load symbols into my memory by using dlopen.

However, I am not sure if this work properly.

My code as following:

```
const char* lib_names[] = {"libudev.so.0.13.0"};
int lib = dlopen(lib_names[0], RTLD_NOLOAD | RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);
```

Is this lib can play a fd for me to judge if this shared object opened properly?

Thanks for any feedback

Comment: If `dlopen()` does not return a NULL, then it is opened properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dlopen()` returns a `void *` pointer.  The pointer is a handle that is passed to the other dynamic linking loader functions.  So, change your return type to `void *`.

```
void *lib = dlopen(...)
```

You can check `lib` to see if the library opened properly.  If `lib` is NULL, then the library failed to open.  If `lib` is not NULL, then the library opened successfully.  Use `dlerror()` to get a textual error string of why the library failed to open.  For example:

```
void *lib = dlopen(...)
if (lib == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Shared library failed to open: %s\n", dlerror());
    exit(1);
}
```

Note that with the `RTLD_NOLOAD` flag set, `dlopen()` won't actually open the library.  From the manual page:

> Don't load the library.  This can be used to test if the library is already resident (dlopen() returns NULL if it is not, or the library's handle if it is resident).  This flag can also be used to promote the flags on a library that is already loaded.  For example, a library that was previously loaded with RTLD_LOCAL  can  be  reopened  with RTLD_NOLOAD | RTLD_GLOBAL.  This flag is not specified in POSIX.1-2001.

You may need to drop `RTLD_NOLOAD` to get the behavior you want.